# IIS 6 Redirect Directory To index.php?

Tags: php, apache, iis, redirect, iis-6

I developed a PHP web application under Apache and am currently in the process of moving it to a server running IIS 6. Whenever I use this application on an Apache server typing this:

```
http://mysite.com/subpage/
```

would internally redirect to:

```
http://mysite.com/subpage/index.php
```

Is there a way within IIS 6 to replicate this same behavior? Simply typing a link without `index.php` give me a director listing denied error. I am not a server administrator, and thus do not have the ability to install an extensions, if they are needed.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On IIS 6 (been a while since I used it) I believe you can set the Default Document in either the application pool setting or the application itself.

In the Default Document properties box, there is a listing of file names and extensions you can set it to load automatically. They are in descending order of priority. You'll want to add index.php to the list and move it to the top.

This will make it so any time you go to a "bare" directory, like http://www.example.com or http://www.example.com/subpage/ it will load up index.php.

If you're trying to do it without administrative access, you can add a Default Document section to your web.config file which then gets used.
http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/defaultDocument

Comment: Thank you, but it looks like this would also require administrative access. Oh, well. :)

Answer (score 2):

As others have answered, if you have direct access to IIS you can set the Default Document.

Without having admin access, you can probably just take advantage of IIS' defaults.  Make a page called "Default.htm" (or "index.htm") that redirects to index.php.  Since those are already set as default documents it should work.

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the default doc for the server to be index.php http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/dc6eb1b4-9028-4308-9935-52b64edfad36.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: Oh... so you would need administrative access for that then. No way to do like in a file like you can with Apache and .htaccess?

Comment: @spryno724: If the server is configured to serve PHP pages, index.php _should_ be configured as one of the "default" documents (not necessarily the first one).